# Which place to put a variable for a nested inner class, android

Tags: android, variables, scope, nested, nested-class

Of the two choices, which is the best place to put the variable of View class in the following example?  In this android app code, is it better to place it as a global variable for the class that extends activity, or is it better to declare the variable inside of the nested inner class called ImageAdapter that extends BaseAdapter?

Which is better?

2 samples of code show below.

in the first sample is where view variable of the View class is declared as more global in scope.  as shown here it appears in the Main class.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
     View view；  // <--- PLACEMENT IN A MORE GLOBAL POSITION
     Cursor imageCursor;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapterview, null);
        }else{
            view = convertView;
        }
```

in this second example View view is declared as a local variable of the ImageAdapter class, inside of the getView method of that class.

```
 public class Main extends Activity {
Cursor imageCursor;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;

   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view；  // <--- PLACEMENT AS LOCAL VARIABLE
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapterview, null);
        }else{
            view = convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason to make `view` a member field. It's use is local to the method, so make it a local variable for the method.

In fact, for this use, you definitely don't want to expose the view to other code in your class. It's supposed to be returned to the framework (that calls `getView`) and then left alone by your code. If you inadvertently make out-of-band changes to the view you return from `getView`, the behavior will be unpredictable.

Comment: yes that makes sense, so i assume that it is always best to restrict scope as much as possible in every situation.  only allow as much scope as needed for that variable.